# iOS view doesn't display any of it's subviews when added as a subview of NavigationController's view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, addsubview

I have a NavigationController and I want to make a View that animates itself from the top of the screen and sits above navigationBar. I'm initialising viewcontroller from a xib and it works perfectly when I add it as `[self.view addSubview:myView];` , but it sits below navigation bar. When I try to add it as `[self.navigationController.view addSubview:myView];` it places it on top of navigationBar as intended but view doesn't display any of it's subviews placed in xib. I can't see why this is happening, have been trying to solve this for hours.

**UPDATE** 
My custom view from a xib is paired with custom ViewController class and I added this code in it :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSLog(@"!!! %i", [self.view.subviews count]);

}
```

if I add myView to self.view it prints 1 (there's actually 1 subview), but when I add it as self.navigationController.view `-viewDidAppear` is not even called. But it does appear on the screen with no subviews. Now I'm even more confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm an idiot. It's a really simple scope problem. I was instantiating a local variable of my VC inside the method, and of course it was released at the end. As soon as I assigned my VC to a global variable all started to work like a charm. Easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use this:

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:myView];

Comment: Nope, still no subviews.

Comment: are you sure, that you add exactly needed view? may be it have not subviews? try to check myView.subviews.count

Comment: I'm sure because when I change this line to `[self.view addSubview:myView];` subviews appear as intended. That's really odd to me.

Comment: Actually I tried to do the count thing, and it prints 0 in both cases even when subviews are actually displayed. I'm confused.

Comment: may be... yours content are showing in other view, and when you remove it (when add to another view), you let them to draw, try just [myView removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just remove the navigation controller if you don't need it? Another way is to hide the navigation bar so that view occupies complete space and then show the navigation bar again when needed.
I could help more if you provide some code with the views.

Comment: It's a solution indeed. The problem here is that I have a view that is a subview of navigationController.view and sits below navigationBar (think of it a as a background to navigationBar that is bigger than the bar itself) and I would have to hide it as well. And the second problem is that the animations won't be as smooth. Placing a view on top of navigationController's view would be a better solution in my case.